# Google Sheets: List of Cryptocurrencies Available for GoogleFinance Funtion?

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

As well as Stocks, my portfolio in Sheets also contains Cryptocurrencies. Is there an updated list of cryptos supported using the GoogleFinance() function anywhere, or do I need to resort to trial and error?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/wiki/featured/cryptocurrency-spreadsheet-utils

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I ended up getting spot prices from CoinGecko. Hopefully I'll be able to figure out the code to get historical prices from them eventually.

Comment: You might also want to check out the API from AlphaVantage.co

Answer (score 1):

As of December, 2022, the IMPORTDATA function works with the cryptoprices.cc site, as described in this article:

https://www.spreadsheetclass.com/pulling-cryptocurrency-prices-into-google-sheets-2-methods/

This worked for me, where a previous solution I used (IMPORTXML) stopped working.

Hope this works for anyone who's been looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

**The list of cryptocurrencies which are currently available is the following:**

- Currency prices provided by Morningstar
- BCH, BTC, ETH, LTC cryptocurrency prices provided by Coinbase, Inc.
- Additional cryptocurrency prices provided by Morningstar

#### Reference

- [Google Finance Disclaimer](https://www.google.com/googlefinance/disclaimer/).